# Copy a string into another without \0

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgets, null-terminated

I have to put a string into another without \0, I tryed a lot of ways but the string is always dirty.

```
char string[100];
int pos=0;

fgets(string, 99, stdin);
len = strlen(string);
printf("%d\n", len);
char array[len-1];

for(pos=0; pos<(len-1); pos++)
    {
      array[j]=string[pos];
      j++;
    }

printf("%s", string);
printf("%s", array);
```

In the terminal I have: 
dogs dogs(ENTER)
10(ENTER)
dogs dogs(ENTER)
dogs dogs@

I also tryed to remove \0 using another symbol but it can't see '\0' or '\n', help me plz!

Comment: So you remove the null terminator from a string and then print it as a null terminated string......?

Comment: Just pointing out = >   `fgets(string, 99, stdin);` **->>** `fgets(string, 100, stdin);` , `fgets` will take care of `'\0'` .

Comment: @ameyCU where did you get `scanf()`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ohh my bad , mistook `printf` for `scanf` . Didn't paid attention .

Comment: If you do not move the \0, the printf won't see the end of the string and will print garbage.

Comment: The real problem is that i need to tokenize the string...

Comment: please explain what you are actually trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing pointer to what is not a null-terminated string to `%s` without length specification will invoke *undefined behavior*. You have to specify the length to print if you hate terminating null-character for some reason.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  int len;

  char string[100];
  int pos=0;

  fgets(string, 99, stdin);
  len = strlen(string);
  printf("%d\n", len);
  char array[len];

  for(pos=0; pos<len; pos++)
      {
        array[pos]=string[pos];
      }

  printf("%s", string);
  printf("%*s", len, array);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I have to delete the \0 cause i have to tokenize the string, and the \0 give me a lot of problem with the last token. But it doesn't work in this way..

Comment: @Nina06 Then the tokenizer must be wrong because strings in C are represented as arrays of characters with terminating null-character.

Comment: @Nina06 Or do you mean literally two characters \ and 0 by `\0`, not a character whose character code is 0?

Comment: Well I suppose it's \0... in reality it's enter: \n

Comment: `char* lf; if ((lf = strchr(string, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';` This is what I use to remove the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You don't want null-terminator, fine. Along with that you should be ready to give up those properties, which comes with the presence of null-terminator. You can no longer make use of the `array` as *string*.

---

To elaborate, in your code, your array `array` is not null-terminated, so it cannot be used as a *string*. the `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to the null-terminated `char` array (in short, a *string*)

So, in your code,

```
printf("%s", array);
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by going past the allocated memory *in search of* the null-terminator.

You can however, print it element by element using a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really don't know how to do, right now, 'cause i have to tokenize the string... of course without \0!!!!!!

Comment: @Nina06 I'm afraid in that case, you need to roll your own parser, standard ones needs a null-terminated array.

Comment: "can however, print it element by element using a for loop." --> Could use `printf("%*s", len, array);`

Answer (score 0):

To copy without the terminating null, use
`memcpy( myCharArray, string, strlen(string) );`
(assumes size of myCharArray is sucfficient). To print out the result, you need to use a loop instead of printf.

Comment: Hmmm  "To print out the result, you need to use a loop instead of printf." -->  maybe `printf("%*s", len, array);`